# How to have function read another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, drop-down-menu, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I need a done variable to close the window when finished with. The menu is also a function. I have tried root1.destory but as the done function can't see what root1 is as it is inside a function it says root1 not defined. How would I have the done function understand what root1 is and close it. Both functions are called for elsewhere. I am using functions as I don't want them to start straight away and only being when called for. My code is:

```
def edit_menu():


    root1 = Tk()
    root1.title("Edit Menu")

    menu = Frame(root1)
    menu.pack(pady = 5, padx = 50)
    var = StringVar(root1)

    options = [
            "Forename",
            "Surname", 
            "Email",
            "Date of birth",
            "Home address",
            "Home phone number",
            "Gender",
            "Tutor group",

]
    option = OptionMenu(menu, var, options[0], *options, command=edit_functions)


    var.set('Select')

    option.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    root1.mainloop()
    return edit_menu

def done():
    print()
    done = (input("If you have finnished editing, type done: "))
    if done == "done":
        root1.destroy()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
  Your posted code is insufficient to show the approach or to elicit an error.

Comment: the 1st problem is you have a function after mainloop. And nothing calls that function anyway.

Comment: There's not enough here to figure out how you expect this to work.  In general, you either make `done` a class method, or pass `root1` to `done` as an argument.  Since there's no class and no main program, it's hard to see what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you just showed us a section of your overall code so this answer may be limited however it should be easy for you to integrate this into your code.

We can put everything we need in the creation of the tkinter window including the done button.

I think you are looking to have something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

def edit_menu():

    root1 = Tk()
    root1.title("Edit Menu")

    menu = Frame(root1)
    menu.pack(pady = 5, padx = 50)
    var = StringVar(root1)

    options = [
            "Forename",
            "Surname", 
            "Email",
            "Date of birth",
            "Home address",
            "Home phone number",
            "Gender",
            "Tutor group",

    ]
    option = OptionMenu(menu, var, options[0], *options)

    var.set('Select')
    option.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    done_btn = Button(root1, text = "Done", command = lambda: root1.destroy())
    done_btn.pack()


    root1.mainloop()

edit_menu()
```

Comment: This is probably an even better way to implement it than what I was trying to do. Thanks.